# The set of combinations has some algebraic structure, similar to the group of permutations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

The set $S_n$ of permutations over $\{1,2,...,n\}$ has a group structure. What if we take the set $C_{k,n}$ of $k$-combinations of $n$ elements? The first I can say is that $S_n$ acts on $C_{k,n}$. Is there any algebraic inner structure in $C_{k,n}$?

Comment: If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over some field $\mathbb{k}$, with distinguished basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, then the $k$th exterior product $\wedge^k V$ has basis $\{e_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k}\colon \{i_1 < \cdots < i_k\} \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, i.e., a basis indexed by "k-combinations." This is the algebraic guise of $\binom{n}{k}$ which comes up the most often, in my experience.

Comment: E.g., if $k = 1$, then $C_{k,n} = \{1,\dots,n\}$. What kind of "algebraic inner structure" can you expect?